# Unexpected Behaviour Using QProcess with PsExec

Tags: powershell, qt, psexec, qprocess

I am facing a problem with QProcess running PsExec.
The PsExec command is responsible for running a powershell script on a remote machine.

The key point which is bothering me is logging. Before I did not have the need to use PsExec but now I do. Basically the running powershell script writes to the Console with `Write-Host` commands. On C++ side I have the signals `QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput` and `QProcess::readyReadStandardError` connected to according slots. The functionality is working.

The problem is that whenever the first `Write-Host` finishes there is no other Write-Host command which succeeds. Additionally there is a message that the powershell.exe is finished with error code 0 which apparently comes from PsExec.exe.

I am not sure what the problem is. I tried to debug it but I can't seem to figure it out.
What also bothers me is that PsExec writes much output to stderr. I read some posts about powershell native-command error but it does not seem to be that case.

Here is the command which is used by QProcess.

```
PsExec.exe -s -nobanner -accepteula \\benjaminvm C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -File C:\Users\benjaminvm\testscript.ps1
```

The content of `testscript.ps1` is simply

```
for ($i = 1 ; $i -le 100 ; $i++)
{
   Write-Host "count = $i"
}
```

When I try to run the command directly in a powershell session on my localhost it gives me all the output I am expecting. It prints every number and then I get the exit message of the powershell session running remotely.

The QProcess object is member of the class Executor.

Executor.h

```
class Executor
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Executor();
private slots:
    void onStdOutputReady();
    void onStdErrorReady();
    void qProcessStarted();
    void qProcessFinished(int p_exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus p_exitStatus);
private:
    QProcess m_executionProcess;
}
```

Executor.cpp

```
Executor::Executor() : m_executionProcess(this)
{
    connect(&m_executionProcess, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, this, &Executor::onStdOutputReady);
    connect(&m_executionProcess, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, this, &Executor::onStdErrorReady);
    connect(&m_executionProcess, &QProcess::started, this, &Executor::qProcessStarted);
    connect(&m_executionProcess, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished), this, &Executor::qProcessFinished);
    m_executionProcess.start("PsExec.exe", QStringList{"-s", "-nobanner","-accepteula", "\\\\benjaminvm" , "C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe", "-File", "C:\\Users\\benjaminvm\\testscript.ps1"});
}
```

Slot for stdout:

```
void Executor::onStdOutputReady()
{
    QString stdOutFromScript = QString::fromStdString(m_executionProcess.readAllStandardOutput().toStdString());
    //Logging ...
}
```

Slot for stderr:

```
void Executor::onStdErrorReady()
{
    QString errorOutputOfProcess = QString::fromStdString(m_executionProcess.readAllStandardError().toStdString());
    //Logging ...
}
```

Can anyone relate?

Comment: How do you set up your `QProcess` object? How do you read from the child-process output? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: I added a minimal example.

Comment: Sorry but that's *not* a [mcve].  At the very least you need to show the code that sets up and calls [`QProcess::start`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#start).

Comment: Now I guess it's suitable. I added the actual start command.